# PPA conflict, removing a PPA in Xubuntu Jammy causes it to try installing the program again

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, ppa

I'm using Xubuntu Jammy and I keep running into problems with "there's not a Jammy release" or something similar. If I understand correctly, it's a problem with a PPA. I don't understand PPAs very well, and I'm having trouble removing an old one and adding a new one so that my various apps install correctly.

When I attempted to remove a problematic PPA using sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:PPA_NAME_HERE, it tried to install the program again instead of removing the PPA. How can I properly remove the old PPA and add a new one to fix the installation issues I'm experiencing?

To be clear, I've had many errors installing many things that say there's a problem with jammy, and I'm not sure whether this PPA from trying to install fsearch is the problem. Thank you.

Here is the output of apt policy:

```
~/.local/bin$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-stable
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-stable/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
A fast file search utility for Unix operating systems
https://cboxdoerfer.github.io/fsearch/
More info: https://launchpad.net/~christian-boxdoerfer/+archive/ubuntu/fsearch-stable
Removing repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                       
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                          
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                      
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                       
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                    
Ign:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mmk2410/intellij-idea-community/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mmk2410/intellij-idea-community/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mmk2410/intellij-idea-community/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
jeff@pistol:~/.local/bin$ apt policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=edge stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=edge stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the user's launchpad, [this particular version of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition is deprecated](https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mmk2410/intellij-idea-community).

You will need to [remove the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/310) from your sources. If you still need software updates from this particular PPA, the developer has another version that seems to be well maintained.

Arguably, it's usually a better idea to use official packages when they exist. The software is available [as a snap](https://snapcraft.io/intellij-idea-community).

Because you mentioned you are not very familiar with PPAs, I suggest you also read: [Are PPAs safe...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)

In general, take care when adding sources to your system, including PPAs. Adding sources changes the library of software for your system. Notably, this can cause problems like dependency issues if you use sources that aren't compatible with each other.